# OpenCV camera calibration about rvecs and tvecs length

Tags: python, opencv

[OpenCV python tutorial calibration](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)

I did what the tutorial does,everything works fine.

But i have a fundemental question about rotation vectors.

I download OpenCV left01-09.jpg and left11-14.jpg

Runned camera calibration with all left*.jpg got rvecs and tvecs seems not match img length.

Input 9 imgs the rvecs and tvecs length is 8,input 13 imgs the rvecs and tvecs length is 11.

Shouldn't rvecs and tvecs length match the input img length if they are taken in totally different position?

Edit : upscale the question to rvecs and tvecs.

Comment: so it's discarding some images because it can't find what it's looking for?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I can tell,it's all about chessboard so i thought it's all good.If some images are discarded,how could we tell the correspondence?

Comment: I can't tell,I typed wrong in my last comment

Comment: read the code. debug it. what do you think, where is that decided? hint: it's somewhere **before** `calibrateCamera`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  Ah!Thanks for this,I just assumed ret will always be true cause the images looks good to me.so if we put those good images in an array,it's label are correspond to rvecs and tvecs right?